# How to display function output in Vue.js template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build a very simple `locale changer` between english and german locale. Basically what I want is a link that displays the opposite locale of what is the `browser default`. So if browser default is `en` I want it to show `de` and vice versa. On click it should change locale and locale displayed in the link.

Below you see an attempt which unfortunately isn't working:

```
<template>
    <a href="#home" @click="changeLocale">{{ notLocale }}</a>
</template>


<script>
import i18n from "../js/i18n";

export default {
  name: "navbar",
  data() {
    return {
      notLocale: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLocale: function () {
      if (i18n.locale == "en") {
        this.notLocale = "de"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

What I tried to do in `methods` is to use `vue-i18n` to check for the `browser locale` and set `notLocale` accordingly.

Important note: I want the opposite of the `browser locale` displayed BEFORE clicking on the link and change on all consecutive clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `privent` modifier to prevent the default behavior of the anchor which is the redirection to the referenced url :

```
@click.prevent="changeLocale"
```

Comment: hey thanks, could you take a look at the `changeLocale` function? It does not work yet. I can't get it to change `noLocale`.

Comment: try to output the `console.log(i18n.locale)` before the if

Comment: `i18n.locale` works. it outputs the current locale

Comment: could you share the screenshot of the output